# iOS Asihttprequest custom progress tracking

Tags: ios, asihttprequest

i'm triyng to show the progress of the download with AsiHttpRequest something like this:
 300 kb / 5 Mb and update constantly the first value.
I understood that if i use -(void)request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request didReceiveData:(NSData *)data i need to manage by myself the nsdata object and write by myself the downloaded file

i've tried this but do not works!!
The mutable data is null!
i use iOS 5 with ARC.
Thanks for any help!

**UPDATED**

I solved with this code, i've set delegate to self and every things work correctly.
Just i do not understand if in this way and with ARC i need to clear the delegate

```
- (void)dealloc
{
   [request clearDelegatesAndCancel];
}
```

Thanks to everybody for the help!!

**UPDATED**

```
-(void)downloadFile: (NSString*) file {
           NSString* urlFilePdf = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mywebsite.com/%@",file];

            myFileName = file;

            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlFilePdf];

            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];


            progressAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"DOWNLOADFILE",nil) message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];

            progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30.0f, 80.0f, 225.0f, 90.0f)];
            [progressAlert addSubview:progressView];
            [progressView setProgressViewStyle: UIProgressViewStyleDefault];

            lblTotal = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 50, 273, 20)];
            [lblTotal setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
            [lblTotal setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:14.0]];
            [lblTotal setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
            [lblTotal setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
            [progressAlert addSubview:lblTotal];

            requestFile = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
            [requestFile setDelegate:self];
            [requestFile setDownloadDestinationPath:filePath];
            [requestFile setDownloadProgressDelegate:self];
            [requestFile setShowAccurateProgress:YES];    
            [progressAlert show];

            [requestFile startAsynchronous];

}

- (void)request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request incrementDownloadSizeBy:(long long)newLength
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"incrementDownloadSizeBy %quKb", newLength/1024]);
}

- (void)request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request didReceiveBytes:(long long)bytes
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"didReceiveBytes %quKb", bytes/1024]);
    currentLength += bytes;
    [lblTotal setText:[NSString    stringWithFormat:@"%quKb/%@",currentLength/1024,self.TotalFileDimension]];
}

- (void)setProgress:(float)newProgress {
    NSLog(@"%f",newProgress);
    progressView.progress = newProgress;
}


-(void) requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    // code ...
}

-(void) requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    // code ...
}

- (void)dealloc
{
   [request clearDelegatesAndCancel];
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, when you decide to manually save the data, you also have to manually handle the progress by checking the length of the data that has been received. As to how you determine the total eventual lenghth…  Not sure.

Comment: Thanks Jacob, i supposed that appendData store the downloaded data step by step. The -(void)request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request didReceiveData:(NSData *)data is constantly called and the size of (NSData *)data if i log it change by the way. but at the end received data is null

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the `request:incrementDownloadSizeBy:` method.

Please note: The title of the question that you wrote is *iOS Asihttprequest custom progress tracking*.  If you look at [the ASIHTTPRequest documentation](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use), you will see a heading that describes exactly what you are asking for - [Custom progress tracking](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#custom_progress_tracking).

If you did not look at this, then that's a huge problem.  You should always check the documentation before asking people for help.

Comment: Thanks Jim i always check the documentation before ask for help. I asked because i tried to implement without success, always return a download error. I asked for for understand if someone have already use this delegate with success. Thanks

Comment: A huge problem?!  Like global warming or famine?